# Shows 1400 post published but don't see them

Tags: import

I have just imported 1400 post from a XMl document they imported well. But I don't  see them in WordPress dashboard. What could be the problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. when I imported a a sql file to wp-post table it has the site link from old site.. So I just replaced these url to the current site using find and replace in notepad++

Now I see all these post

Answer (score 1):

Use `WP_ALLOW_REPAIR` property and set it as `TRUE` in **wp-config.php**

**wp-config.php**

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you access your WordPress database it might be that they have a different `post_status`. I've worked on a few plugins and when I was creating new status' I got this same effect where it wouldn't show me anything. Also, in `wp-config.php`set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` and it may show you the error you're getting.

Comment: This also happened to me after disabling a custom post status plugin; might as well happen if you migrate the posts with a custom status from one site to another.